# Can not import a class from another file in the same directory in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, singleton

I am quite new to Python and I am still getting used to it. I have a project which was written by using a bunch of files containing only function definitions. I decided to remake it in OOP paradigm so this is what happens:

Back then, I had these two files:

```
Main
 | ---- loggingManager.py
 | ---- servoManager.py
```

in the servoManager.py script I had:

```
from loggingManager import *
...
from time import sleep
```

and it all works fine. I can use all of the functions **def**ined in loggingManager.py without any issues.

Now I have it like this:

```
Main
 | ---- Logger.py
 | ---- ConfigurationWrapper.py
```

The content of the ConfigurationWrapper is :

```
import configparser

class ConfigurationWrapper:
    default_path = '/home/pi/Desktop/Bree/config.ini'

    def __init__(self, path_to_file=None):
        if path_to_file is None:
            path_to_file = self.default_path
...
```

and Logger looks like this:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwarg$
        else:
            cls._instances[cls].__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        return cls._instances[cls]

class Logger():
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
```

My goal here is to import:

```
import ConfigurationWrapper
```

in Logger.py script file but every time I do that, I get an error (by typing 'python Logger' in the terminal on MacOS):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Logger", line 1, in <module>
    import ConfigurationWrapper
ImportError: No module named ConfigurationWrapper
```

I tried to add empty __ init __.py file in the same folder but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dot (.) before the imported module

`import .ConfigurationWrapper`

or import your class

`from .ConfigurationWrapper import ConfigurationWrapper`

The dot (.) means that you're importing from the same directory.

Comment: Both of these are not working. I the first case I get 'invalid syntax' on the dot and in the second case 'Attempted relative import in non-package'.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was to add:

```
execfile("./ConfigurationWrapper")
```

but I'd like to know how appropriate is that.